# Pub/Sub to BigQuery template

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Currently evaluating stream process from pub/sub to bq by using [template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/HEAD/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) that provided by Google and keep getting this error:

[image]

Schema of the message in the BQ is matched. But somehow job is not able to write message to BQ.  Any ideas what could be the issue on this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an information error because  you get an error while inserting the data into BigQuery.

You need to validate these things:

- Some fields are missing.
- The type of the data you are inserting mismatches with the table
  schema.
- A mandatory field has no data.
- A date  does not have  the correct format.

You can execute this code in the terminal to get more information about this error.

```
bq --format=prettyjson show -j <JobID>
```

It will return a JSON with more details.  You can see this example:

```
"message": "Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '16.66666666666667' as int for field Course_Percentage (position 46) starting at location 1717164"
```

You can see this document about [troubleshooting streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#streaming).

You can use this option: go to the “Logging” section, then “Logs Explorer” in the console, and see more details about errors.

[image]

You can filter the error by product name, in this case “Dataflow” or “Bigquery”.

[image]

Use another filter by hour.

[image]

You’ll see all the errors by product, and if you click each one, you’ll see more details about this specific error.

[image]

You can see this documentation about [logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface).

Comment: That job for BQ check.  I am having issue with DataFlow.

Comment: @Askar It's correct, you are using Dataflow, but at the same time you are using Bigquery triying to insert the data in the step 3 of the DataFlow job "Elements that failed inserts into BigQuery", which in this part is failing. This is because something is wrong in the data you send and cannot be inserted in BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks Raul, that make sense the issue something with BQ when inserting data.  The command that you pasted will not check Dataflow job but BQ.  I am feeling that this still in `Beta` https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#pubsub-topic-to-bigquery

Comment: @Askar I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Raul, I went through that before.  There is not much explanation since it is in Beta still. I opened case with Google to get more info on that.  They are still investigating.